# Comparing ASP.NET Page Life Cycle in NET 3.5 and NET 4

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

Is it some difference in ASP.NET Page Life Cycle comparing NET 3.5 and NET 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you are using ASP.NET web forms and not MVC, I think it's safe to say that no, there is not. They're identical.